# Create dynamic SQL Update from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, sql, arrays, typescript, sql-update

I have an array of objects with which I am trying to create an Update SQL.

This is my `array`:

```
let dataUpdate = [
  {
     "field1":123,
     "field2":"BMW",
     "field3":"blue"
  }
]
```

This is what I am trying to do:

```
let query: string = `UPDATE dataset.table SET` + dataTest.forEach((item:any) =>
  Object.entries(item).map(([key,value]) => {
    `${key} = '${value}'`
  }).join(',')
)
```

This is what I get:

```
UPDATE dataset.table SETundefined
```

This is what I need:

```
UPDATE dataset.table SET field2="BMW", field3="blue" WHERE field1=123
```

Comment: either missing return statement or too much curly brackets. btw, you could quote single quotes as well.

Comment: @NinaScholz The array can contain multiple objects, so I loop through it first. But then I don't know how to form the query, to join the fields of the SET with the string

Comment: your update statement needs some identifier for selecting the row. what should happen, if you have more than one item in the array?

Comment: Don't forget to sanitize the data before creating and executing the query ;)

Comment: @NinaScholz An Update query should be created for each object in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate the criteria from the update. I created a function called `updateQuery`, that constructs the desired query, below.

```js
const quote = (val) => typeof val === 'string' ? `"${val}"` : val;

const updateQuery = (table, criteria, update) =>
  `UPDATE ${table} SET ${Object.entries(update)
    .map(([field, value]) => `${field}=${quote(value)}`)
    .join(', ')} WHERE ${Object.entries(criteria)
    .map(([field, value]) => `${field}=${quote(value)}`)
    .join(' AND ')}`;

const expected = 'UPDATE dataset.table SET field2="BMW", field3="blue" WHERE field1=123';

const actual = updateQuery(
  'dataset.table',
  { 'field1': 123 },
  { 'field2': 'BMW', 'field3': 'blue' }
);

console.log(expected === actual);
```